# MYSQL remove duplicates where multiple columns match

Tags: mysql

I have a table > 500,000 rows where there are duplicate entries that need to be removed but only where a few columns match.

The main table has the following columns

```
id,
countryID,
postalCode,
adminName1,
adminName2,
placeName,
adminName3,
latitude,
longitude
```

I need to remove duplicates (leaving the first record) where 
placeName, latitude & longitude match

I had a search and found this which looks right but doesnt work for me.
I have duplicated the original table structure into a new table (tblTemp)

```
INSERT INTO tblTemp(id,countryID,postalCode,adminName1,adminName2,placeName,adminName3,latitude,longitude)
SELECT DISTINCT placeName,latitude,longitude
FROM tblCountry_admin;
```

But i get the error

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Ofcourse it will. You are trying to insert 3 values into 9 columns.

Comment: Please specify which row to consider in case there are multiple rows with same placeName,latitude,longitude ... Maybe max id?

Answer (score 1):

if you want delete the duplicate row by laceName, latitude & longitude leaving the the old one  you could

You could check for select the duplicated rows  this wat

```
  select * from tblCountry_admin
  where id not in (
     select min(id)
     from tblCountry_admin
     group by placename, latitude, longitude
     )
```

then you could delete this way

```
delete from tblCountry_admin
where id not in (
   select min(id)
   from tblCountry_admin
   group by placename, latitude, longitude
   )
```

*the error you get in you insert select id due by the fact the number of column in insert don't match the number of column is select*

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE`:

```
INSERT INTO tblTemp (id, countryID, postalCode, adminName1,adminName2,     
                     placeName, adminName3, latitude, longitude)
    SELECT id, countryID, postalCode, adminName1, adminName2,
           placeName, adminName3, latitude, longitude
    FROM tblCountry_admin a
    WHERE a.id = (SELECT MIN(a2.id)
                  FROM tblCountry_admin a2
                  WHERE a2.placeName = a.placeName AND
                        a2.latitude = a.latitude AND
                        a2.longitude = a.longitude
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `tblTemp` has same set of columns as `tblCountry_admin` and you want to get the rows with max id in case of duplicates, you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO tblTemp
select a.*
from tblCountry_admin a left join tblCountry_admin b on a.placeName = b.placeName
    and a.latitude = b.latitude
    and a.longitude = b.longitude
    and a.id < b.id
where b.id is null;
```

If you want to create the table *using* the select use:

```
create table tblTemp as
select a.*
from tblCountry_admin a left join tblCountry_admin b on a.placeName = b.placeName
    and a.latitude = b.latitude
    and a.longitude = b.longitude
    and a.id < b.id
where b.id is null;
```

Comment: This option is taking a vlong time to run and if i interrupt it no entries have been added to tblTemp

Comment: Working on half a million records is ***going*** to take time. It'll however be faster than group by operation provided proper indexes were in place in your original table.